# Configuration management and control for OpenLDAP

Tags: openldap

I have an OpenLDAP server set up with LDIF/OLC configuration (all configuration is done on-line).

What are the best practices to allow versioning this configuration àla `git`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The practice I've seen recommended most often is to dump the config database (`slapcat -n0`), either periodically as a cron job or on demand, and check the output into version control.

An alternative is to `git init` the config database directory itself. I don't know a lot about the pros or cons of this approach.